# Sorting by 2 Custom Fields + Post Title

Tags: query-string

So I've successfully sorted my custom post type "property" based on it's city and state using this:

```
<?php
$querystr = "
SELECT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'state'
AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'city'
AND wposts.post_type = 'property'
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC, wpostmeta2.meta_value ASC
";$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);?>
```

Now I'd like to add a third sorter, which would just be the post title (the name of the property). How can I add this in? What is the proper name for identifying the post title as part of the query string?

Answer (score 1):

Check:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

and you will see that's post_title then in your order part of the query you will refer to

```
wpost.post_title
```

Comment: Thank you -- wposts.post_title did the trick (you forgot the "s" in wposts)